# Will windows phone app with target version 8.0 run on 7 or 7.1?

Tags: windows-phone

Initially i developed my windows phone app with version 7.1 but later i upgraded it to target the version 8.0 .
Now my doubt is that will my app work in windows phone 7.1 version??

Thank You in Advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No it won't. Keep it in 7.1 if you don't make use of any special features available only in 8.0. Or maintain two project version as explained in [Nokia Developer Community Wiki](http://developer.nokia.com/Community/Wiki/Maintaining_a_WP7_and_WP8_version_of_a_same_Silverlight_application) if you need some feature in 8.0 platform but want to keep support for 7.1. You can [submit two .XAP version](http://blog.kgoutsos.gr/different-xap) -for WP 8.0 and 7.1- for one application in Windows Phone Marketplace.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot convert a windows phone 8 app to Windows Phone 7.1, but you can target both versions. Details on how the whole process works can be found [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsphone/develop/jj207030%28v=vs.105%29.aspx).

Answer (score 0):

Hy,

if you have upgraded to 8.0 WindowsPhoone you can no longer perform in WindowsPhone downgrade to 7.1, my advice if you want to continue to develop for both operating systems keep 2 copies of the project